# Saving an array containing some empty elements using saveAll

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an array containing many arrays with data which I want to save using `saveAll` or `saveMany`. However, due to factors I can not change, not all arrays are actually containing any data. In the dump you can see below, only the first two arrays are filled.

When saving this array with `saveAll` or `saveMany`, I receive the following error:`Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'productinfo_id' cannot be null`.

How can I avoid this error when saving the arrays using saveAll or saveMany?

```
array(
    (int) 1 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '68',
        'quantity' => '30',
        'productName' => 'ciplorex syp 125',
        'pack' => '60ml',
        'purchasePrice' => '49.30',
        'grossAmount' => '1479.00',
        'discountPercent' => '20.00',
        'discountAmount' => '295.80',
        'netAmount' => '1183.20'
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '69',
        'quantity' => '27',
        'productName' => 'ciplorex syp 250',
        'pack' => '60ml',
        'purchasePrice' => '85.00',
        'grossAmount' => '2295.00',
        'discountPercent' => '20.00',
        'discountAmount' => '459.00',
        'netAmount' => '1836.00'
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 4 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 5 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 6 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 7 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 8 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 9 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 10 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 11 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 12 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 13 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 14 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 15 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 16 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 17 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 18 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 19 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 20 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 21 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 22 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 23 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 24 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 25 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 26 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 27 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 28 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 29 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    ),
    (int) 30 => array(
        'purchaseinfo_id' => '7',
        'productinfo_id' => '',
        'quantity' => '',
        'productName' => '',
        'pack' => '',
        'purchasePrice' => '',
        'grossAmount' => '',
        'discountPercent' => '',
        'discountAmount' => '',
        'netAmount' => ''
    )
)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thank you for your question. I have quickly applied some modifications to your question to make it more understandable. I hope you don't mind. If you do, please feel free to revert back to a previous revision. If you have any questions, take a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Have fun!

Comment: What do you want do with the empty product?

Answer (score 1):

Before saving the array, I would suggest looping over it and filtering the empty arrays. Example:

```
$originalArray = #Your Data;

$saveArray = array();

foreach($originalArray as $item) {
    if(!empty($item['productinfo_id'])) {
        $saveArray[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Then you can feed the new array to the `saveAll` method.

Answer (score 1):

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'productinfo_id' cannot be null

I assume you understand what this means? You're required to pass a value into this field, you can't save a table row with an empty `productinfo_id`. Also I think this should be called `product_info_id`.

So instead of filtering empty arrays, like suggested by Lars, I would first ask the question: Why are they present at all? I would avoid that.

The proper solution to avoid the hard error you'll get when the SQL error happens would be [to use validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html) in the model to make sure the record can't be saved at all and fails validation on an empty `product_info_id`. This will ensure a graceful and meaningful way to handle this.

Additionally to this you can filter out "empty" associated records in the beforeSave() callback. But this is *not* the primary fix for this, the validation is.